# How to add logo on background image using html css

Tags: html, css, image

I want to put a logo on background image please guide me how to do it

```css
body {
  background: url("../graphics/homepage-image.jpg") no-repeat top left;
  background-size: cover;
  clear: both;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.logo {
  background: url("../graphics/dhaka logo.png");
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="logo">

  </div>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href=""></a>Login</li>
      <li>
        <a href=""></a>Sign up</li>
      <li>
        <a href=""></a>Contact us</li>
      <li>
        <a href=""></a>Feedback</li>
      <li>
        <a href=""></a> About us </li>
      <li>
        <a href=""></a> Home</li>



    </ul>

  </nav>



  <div id="footer">

    <p>&copy; Copyrights Dhaka Bangladesh 2015</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why not putting the logo in a div?

Comment: How to do it please guide me i used to do the same i created <div id=logo> logo image </div>

Answer (score 2):

Just add `background-repeat: no-repeat;` and `background-size: cover;` in `logo` CSS.

```
.logo {
      background-image: url("../graphics/dhaka logo.png");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
}
```

> **Avoid spaces in file/image name like `dhaka logo.png` you can replace space with `%20` like `dhaka%20logo.png`**. But i would suggest to change your image name `dhaka-logo.png`.

You can see the [W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri) for the full requirements.

```css
body {
  background: url("../graphics/homepage-image.jpg") no-repeat top left;
  background-size: cover;
  clear: both;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.logo {
  background-image: url("../graphics/dhaka logo.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href=""></a>Login</li>
      <li><a href=""></a>Sign up</li>
      <li><a href=""></a>Contact us</li>
      <li><a href=""></a>Feedback</li>
      <li><a href=""></a> About us </li>
      <li><a href=""></a> Home</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>&copy; Copyrights Dhaka Bangladesh 2015</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the logo in a div

```
<div id="my_logo"></div>
```

And then style it:

```
#my_logo{
    background: url"../graphics/dhaka logo.png");
    width : your_logo_width;
    height : your_logo_height;
}
body{
background: url("../graphics/homepage-image.jpg") no-repeat top left;

overflow: hidden;

background-size:cover;
clear:both;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: i'm doing the same but it doesn't work my logo image is hidden but occupied some space according to height and width

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{

background: url('http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-logo32.png') no-repeat;
 
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
 background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
    
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

```css
.logo {
  background-image: url('http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-logo32.png');
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<style>
body {
background: url("../graphics/homepage-image.jpg") no-repeat top left;
background-size:cover;
clear:both;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}

.logo {    
background-image: url('../graphics/dhaka logo.png'); 
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
width:150px;
height:50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body> 

           <ul> 
               <li><a href=""></a>Login</li>
               <li><a href=""></a>Sign up</li>
               <li><a href=""></a>Contact us</li>
               <li><a href=""></a>Feedback</li>
               <li><a href=""></a> About us </li>
               <li><a href=""></a> Home</li>
           </ul>
    <div class="logo"> 
    </div>
      <div id="footer">

          <p>&copy; Copyrights Dhaka Bangladesh 2015</p> 
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <body> 

<div class="logo"> 

</div>

      <nav>
          <ul> 
               <li><a href=""></a>Login</li>
      <li><a href=""></a>Sign up</li>
      <li><a href=""></a>Contact us</li>
      <li><a href=""></a>Feedback</li>
      <li><a href=""></a> About us </li>
      <li><a href=""></a> Home</li>



    </ul>
      
   </nav>
 
 

   <div id="footer">
   
       <p>&copy; Copyrights  2015</p> 
   </div>


</body>

Comment: is there going to be content going over the image? Does it really need to be a background image?